# Accessing my tomcat server remotely

Tags: tomcat, remote-access, server

I have a tomcat server running on my pc which I can access locally via: `http://localhost:9090` (I changed the ports in the server.xml file). Now, I am having trouble accessing the tomcat server remotely (i.e. a different machine, I can test this with machines outside or inside of my LAN).

Anyway, what I have tried is using the netgear genie interface to configure port forwarding. I have set all internal and external ports to 9090 (I tried using 80 for internal and 8080 for external but I they were already being used).

When I point my browser to: `http://my-ip-address:9090` and it just times out... If I don't add a port, I am prompted with a username and password with a message box that says:

> A username and password are being requested by `http://my-ip-address.`
>   The site says: "SMC Dual WAN Load balancing VPN Router Administration
>   Tools"

This is NOT the same as the username and password that I needed to login to the netgear genie interface. Note that I use Ubuntu (12.04, 13.04 and 14.04) and tomcat7.

Please help me get connected to my tomcat server remotely.

Thanks for all the help, and let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to open up port 9090 in your linux firewall.  I would recommend using ufw (uncomplicated firewall) to open up the port.  If you don't have it installed you can get it from the package manager or from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

Enable ufw:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Check the status:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

Open up port 9090:

```
sudo ufw allow 9090
```

Check the status again to make sure 9090 is open then see if you can get to it from another machine.  For more on ufw: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Comment: Is it possible to test this with my internet IP address locally? I obtained my ip address from google and then pointed my browser to: `http://my-ip-address:9090` and it still did not work :(

Comment: First you need to try with another machine on your lan using the lan ip address of that server.  Once that is confirmed, it is a matter of configuring your router properly forward 9090 to the lan address of your ubuntu server, port 9090. You'll want to make sure you permanently assign a local lan address to the ubuntu server in your router.

Comment: I have successfully tried with another computer on my lan, and I am port forwarding 9090 to 9090 with my router -- I must be doing something wrong... What would you look deeper into next?

Comment: Great - that narrows it down to the router. Go to http://ident.me and make sure that ip address matches what you expect (what you got from google). You've probably already done this, but get your local ip address using ifconifg and make sure that's what you used in your ipforwarding.

Comment: Can you give me a quick example of what I should type in? I get an interface from my router that wants `External Start Port, External End Port, Internal Start Port, Internal End Port, Internal IP address.` I used 9090, 9090, 9090, 9090, and 192.168.1.2 for these 5 fields -- does that make sense?

Comment: That is correct.  Is there an option for protocol, set to tcp? (or both tcp and udp)

Comment: Yes, I chose tcp/udp which means both

Comment: Who do you have as your Internet service provider? It looks like they may be blocking your access- especially given the message you get when going through without a port (normally doing so would bring up your router's configuration interface).

Comment: That is interesting, I alive in an apartment so a lot of things are not up to me (I wonder if they do this so you can't setup your own webserver) -- we just got a new provider so I'm going to go swap out the modem/router and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, some providers do this on purpose for exactly that reason. They will usually give you an option for a "business plan" that includes a static ip for which you have access to all ports.